# URISyntax exception while sending HTTP request to Solr from Java play framework

Tags: java, solr, playframework, playframework-2.0, urlencode

I am getting URISyntaxException when I make an HTTP request using the WS.url() API of play framework in java.
Below is the stack trace of the excetption.

```
   play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[IllegalArgumentException: null]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:841) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at com.ning.http.client.RequestBuilderBase.buildURI(RequestBuilderBase.java:390) ~[async-http-client.jar:na]
    at com.ning.http.client.RequestBuilderBase.setUrl(RequestBuilderBase.java:373) ~[async-http-client.jar:na]
    at play.libs.WS$WSRequest.setUrl(WS.java:137) ~[play-java_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.libs.WS$WSRequestHolder.execute(WS.java:454) ~[play-java_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.libs.WS$WSRequestHolder.get(WS.java:352) ~[play-java_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 419: http://solrUrl.com/solr/catalog/select?facet=true&fl=identifier_ntk,catgroup_id,name,shortDescription,thumbnail,sequence,parentCatgroup_id_facet,childCatgroup_id,storeent_id,childCatentry_id&debugQuery=false&start=0&q=*:*&timeAllowed=15000&json.nl=map&wt=json&fq=storeent_id:(%2210001%22)&fq=catalog_id:%2210001%22&fq=parentCatgroup_id_facet:(+10001_\-1)&version=2&rows=50
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2810) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2983) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3073) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3015) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:577) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:839) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
```

Can you help me resolve this?

Comment: are you seeing to get any response with the URL in the stacktrace on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be a Solr problem:

> Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 419: 
>   http://solrUrl.com/solr/catalog/select?facet=true&fl=identifier_ntk,catgroup_id,.....
>
> at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2810) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
>      at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2983) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
>      at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3073) ~[na:1.6.0_65]

Looks like the URL might be mis-shaped on the play side. The index seem to be pointing at the last or one after last character. I would print that URL before trying to open it and see if there is something funny in it. Like having a wrong newline at the end of the URL or something similar.